# Generate random chars and integers in C++

Tags: c++

How do I generate random chars and integers within a method so that the method can be called in main() and so that the method generates random chars and integers **together.** I **do not** want a method that genrates chars and another methods that generates integers.

Comment: Do you want them one at a time, maybe alternating chars and ints, or do you want a parameter that tells how many to generate? What do you want to use the randomly generated values for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a method like (assuming you want only lower case English characters, you can extend it):

```
void generate(char& ranChar, int& ranNmber)
{
  //Generate a random number in the range 0-25 and add the ascii value 'a'
  ranChar = rand() % 26 + 'a';
  ranNumber = rand();
}

int main()
{
   //Seed the random number generator with the current time
   srand(time(NULL));
   char ch;
   int n= 0;
   generate(ch,n);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the 27th letter of the English alphabet?  :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html), like this:

```
boost::tuple<int, char> gen () {
// srand() etc
return make_tuple(rand(), (rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1)) + 'a');
}
```